# Import suggestions not working cocoa pods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

When i write a `#import "XyzLib.h"` line manuanlly, then build is working fine.

However when I type `#import "Xy"` and press `Esc` button, Then suggestion is not showing up.

Comment: You should be using the `#import <LibName/LibFile.h>` syntax by the way, that is the correct format for an external library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding `${PODS_ROOT}` to your project's `Build Settings -> User Header Search Paths`, Xcode will fetch your current root directory where the pods are installed, and the suggestions will become active.

Comment: Had to build the project too

Answer (score 1):

I added `${PODS_ROOT}` to `Build Settings` -> `User Header Search Paths`
I fixed the auto suggestion of cocoa pods libs.